# How to make a JQuery drop-down appear in the right place?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not familiar at all with JQuery and I'm not very good with CSS, but nonetheless I find myself working with it. So, basically here's my dilemma:

I have a simple jquery script where you click on an image and a little login box drops down using slideToggle. I took a script someone had already written to do this, but their script had `position: relative`, and so it would push the rest of the elements around as it dropped. I changed it to `position: absolute` so that it would appear on top, but now it doesn't appear below the image, it appears on the left side of the screen. I'm thinking this has something to do with blocks or whatever (like it's appearing in the next biggest container on the left side, or something?), but like I said my knowledge of this is pretty minimal.

Here is the CSS code to determine what the little menu looks like:

```
.menu_body {display:none; width:200px;border-right:1px solid #998675;border-bottom:1px solid #998675;border-left:1px solid #998675; position: absolute;}
```

It's got a display:none so that it doesn't appear at first (you must click the image to make it appear), and everything else there probably isn't too interesting. Is there some tag or attribute I can add to this in order to make it float as well as appear in the correct location? Given the small amount of info I put up here, can anyone tell me why it aligns to the left?

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting top and left in CSS